# Consulta compleja en Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models

**Tengo la siguiente tabla con los siguientes registros:**

```
|id | datetime | state_id | brand_id | customer_id | recommender_id |
|---|----------|----------|----------|-------------|----------------|
| 1 | ...      |   5      |     1    |     32      |       31       |
| 2 | ...      |   5      |     1    |     32      |       19       |
| 3 | ...      |   5      |     9    |     32      |       8        |
| 4 | ...      |   5      |     28   |     32      |       8        |
| 5 | ...      |   6      |     1    |     32      |       8        |
```

La entidad en el modelo se llama **Recommender**. `brand_id` y `customer_id` son llaves foráneas de **User**.

Y estoy diseñando una consulta utilizando `Django 2` que me retorne todos los registros donde, el **customer_id** sea igual usuario logueado (`request.user`) y el **state** sea igual a 5. Esta es mi consulta y funciona:

```
recommend = Recommender.objects.all().filter(
  customer=request.user, authorized=State.objects.get(pk=5)
)
```

La consulta anterior me retorna todos los registros en estado 5 (con `customer = request.user`).
Sin embargo, necesito que cuando ***una*** pareja (brand_id, customer_id) tenga state 6 (como el último registro de la tabla anterior), no me retorne en la consulta ***ningún*** registro de esa pareja en estado 5.

¿ Como podría realizar esa consulta usando el ORM de Django ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer una condición (if) con una búsqueda previa que te diga si existe un Recommender que con el state 6 con los campos por los que quieres filtrar, en caso de que exista, no haces el filtro.

Ejemplo:

```
if not Recommender.objects.filter(customer=request.user, brand = brand, state=6).exist():
    recommend = Recommender.objects.all().filter(
        customer=request.user, authorized=State.objects.get(pk=5))
```

También puedes obtener tanto los que tienen `state = 5` y `state = 6` y después pasarle por el if. Ésta segunda forma hará que la función sea más lenta.